# Mysql: Is it possible to handle 1000 concurrent while having low cpu?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, mysql-5.5, proxysql

We're running Centos 7, we're in the process Mariadb 5.5, upgrading to 10.3 today. PHP 5.

The queries are bad, and there are far too many of them to optimize, but I'm trying what I can, the database structure is bad.

The client doesn't care about query optimization, he just wants to lower CPU usage, he runs [locust](https://locust.io/), a load testing tool, give it 1500 users and 1000 concurrent, sees the CPU at in the 90s % and says this is bad. The search functionality is the problem he said.

Again I'm telling you, the queries are bad, I just got hired and doing what I can, but is he looking at the right metrics?

What have I tried to do other than fixing queries:

Adding indexes, there were no indexes, also `my.cnf`

```
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown =1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup =1
## innodb_buffer_pool_instances should match the number of cores on the server

innodb_log_file_size = 2047M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
sync_binlog=0
innodb_thread_concurrency = 48
innodb_read_io_threads = 24
innodb_write_io_threads = 24

## set innodb_buffer_pool to 50% to 70% of the ram on the server so if the server have 32G, then set it to 16G. 50% is a good start
## turn off slow query log, if you're not logging, and only log for small durations when you want to monitor things
slow_query_log =0
```

I tried to optimize what I can from the slow query log as well. Also trying to use proxySQL, which I heard it intercepts the query and sends 1/10 of the queries to the server, because of caching.

The client has a streaming app, during peak events, he hits 7k users, not sure if that counts as concurrent users and highly doubt that all of them would search. They have an on-premise server

DL380 Gen10
2x Intel Xeon Silver 4110 / 2.1 GHz
64 GB RAM
300 GB HDD

My questions:

1. Is there any measure one could take that I didn't know about to
   reduce the CPU usage of search queries?
2. If I were to optimize all the queries, would I expect lower CPU under such a load test? They want the CPU usage to drop to like 50%, I just feel that they're looking at the wrong metrics. They have the right to do so because it used to be that whenever cpu got to 100%, server would go down.

Comment: You're running a load test tool, which purposely stress tests & uses CPU *on purpose*, the queries are admittedly bad, yet someone is complaining about high CPU usage? This all makes zero sense. The answer to your question is: Tune your queries

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ if all the queries get tuned, would you expect cpu usage in the 50s% for 1000 concurrent users? Isn't mysql going to use that much cpu even then?

Comment: Depends on what the test is doing and if the application will become the bottleneck. The server could still run at 100 percent but the test could finish faster.

Comment: *"The client doesn't care about query optimization, he just wants to lower CPU usage, he runs locust, a load testing tool, give it 1500 users and 1000 concurrent, sees the CPU at in the 90s % and says this is bad. The search functionality is the problem he said."*  Sounds like the client is a manager not a developer and not knows what he is talking about..

Comment: *"he runs locust, a load testing tool, give it 1500 users and 1000 concurrent, sees the CPU at in the 90s % and says this is bad."* ... also it feels like that MySQL and the webserver is running on one and the same machine plus the CPU time of locust is most likely also measured.. ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland He is a manager, I can't argue with him because I'm a developer and because the queries are indeed bad, rewriting them is a must but I'm not sure I'll be able to show him lower cpu, because I've seen healthy databases with 100% cpu. The webserver and the database are running on the same machine, is this a problem?

Comment: *"He is a manager, I can't argue with him because I'm a developer "* Right the typical manager / developer sparring sessions..    Manager says something is bad because it is slow.. Developer give the manager right, analyse the code which worked maybe for 3 year fine and fast and says it is bad and the code needs to be rewritten..  Manager will not believe it as it worked for 3 years fine and disallowes rewritting it..

Comment: *"He is a manager, I can't argue with him because I'm a developer and because the queries are indeed bad, rewriting them is a must but I'm not sure I'll be able to show him lower cpu, because I've seen healthy databases with 100% cpu."* i wonder why IT specialists always need to proof something to a manager before they trust them.. Anyhow that system also seams not modern, the data most likely  increased alot when the code was first written meaning MySQL has more processing to on those bad structures and indexes

Comment: Or the manager needs to buy a beter machine or the code needs to optimized to handle that larger amount of data..

Comment: @Lynob         Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
From SSH root login, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Lynob         innodb_thread_concurrency should be 0 to allow system auto calc per dba.stackexchange.com Question 5666 - see Rolando's info dated 9/12/2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to identify which 'bad' query to fix that will give you the most bang for the buck:  The slowlog plus `pt-query-digest`.  More details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

I rarely need to go down the list more than 3 items to make a dramatic improvement.

If you are weak on knowing what indexes to add, don't simply "index ever column".  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

> Is there any measure one could take that I didn't know about to reduce the CPU usage of search queries?

No.  High CPU is fixed by using selected composite indexes and/or reformulating the queries.  Show us the queries.  "Search" is too vague a term.

Here's an extreme anecdote:  The CPU was pegged at 100%.  The slowlog pointed at one query.  It had `WHERE DATE(foo) = '...'`.  By making that "sargable", the CPU dropped to 2%.

As for benchmarks...  Beware.  They tend to see how many connections they can run before running out of horsepower.  That is, the results are guaranteed to say 100% CPU!  The real metric they get out is "queries/second" or "maximum connections".

Furthermore, it has repeatedly been documented that if you push mysql beyond some number of concurrent users, throughput goes down!  A decade ago, that number was about 6; now it is more like 64.  But 1000?  No way.  It is spinning its wheels because all 1000 are stumbling over each other.

How to handle 1000 users?  Replication feeding multiple Slaves.  With such, you could have 1000 slaves, each running a mere 10 connections; CPU will be very low.  Etc.

Comment: To explain the *"sargable"* term which was used here.. A few *"sargable"*  versions off `WHERE DATE(date_time) = '2019-10-23'` could be `WHERE DATE(date_time) LIKE '2019-10-23%'` (evil auto casting) or the some better ones `WHERE date_time => '2019-10-23' AND date_time < '2019-10-23' + INTERVAL 1 DAY` (should be preprocessed/optimized as `'2019-10-24'` anyway) ... `WHERE date_time => '2019-10-23' AND date_time < '2019-10-24'`

Comment: @RaymondNijland - When the curve flattens, it means that latency is suffering, but the pages continue to be processed.  The processes are stumbling over each other, taking longer to finish.  When the curve takes a nose dive, both latency and throughput suffer.

Comment: ... also keep in mind that left scale is webpages per second so the latency could also be caused by other things aswell.. but removed mine comments about this anyway as the benchmark also feels a bit to much staged and unclear what and how it was benchmark

Answer (score 1):

> The queries are bad

Then they need fixing. You *could* add extra hardware but you will get linear improvements at best, fixing the queries could potentially give several orders of magnitude of improvement by removing huge scans and such. Though I'm only guessing here as we have no information about the actual queries.

> and there are far too many of them to optimize

There may be far to many to optimise immediately, but you can take metrics and attack the worst offenders first. This won't always be the complex ones either: a simple sub-optimal query that is run many times in a given period will be better to attack first than a massive complex report that is run once per month.

> the database structure is bad.

This may impede improving the queries, especially if the bad design isn't just a lack of good index choices. Working on both together may be the best plan in the long run, but it will take more work to see the first beneficial results. Again you give no specifics so we can only give vague answers/guesses.